How to Add Images to Android Studio 2024 Ladybug?
I am trying to add images to my android app by adding to res->drawable->image asset.But images are not adding. It is adding images as icons and not as background images.
Please help to add app images to android as image assets.

What type of your image (.svg, .png, etc.)?

Resource Manager --> then click on "+ icon"(add resource to module) -->Import Drawable option working for me in Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2.

In android ladybug when i click add image asset i get this box. And i allows only icons and banners. I am unable to add an ordinary image.


I think I found a solution. Put those lines on your Gradle, inside the Android space:
sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

And you can now add it, Move it to your folder in commonmain if Android Studio saves them on main, and build the project.
